# Finding y when given x

Tags: python, interpolation

I am trying to find the value of y at a given x. I find the maximum value in an array for one file (I am analyzing multiple files). Make for loop to iterate through every file. I want to find my y value, when my x(MaxPL_IM3) is given even though that value will most likely not be a value in my array.

```
#lenght is the number of files being read
#PL and IM3_hi are initialized at the beginning of the code since I 
#grab the data from external files

IM3_value=[None]*length
f=[None]*length
#finds max in PL array for one file
for c in range(0,length):
    MaxPL_IM3[c]=max(PL[c])
MaxPL_IM3[:]=[x-3 for x in MaxPL_IM3]

for c in range(0,length):
    #PL[c] should be the array of data for one file
    #IM3_hi[c] should be the array of data for one file

    f[c]=interp1d(PL[c],IM3_hi[c]) #interpolate array vs array for 
    #one file
    IM3_value[c]=f[MaxPL_IM3[c]]
    print(IM3_value[c])
```

I run this and I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
IM3_value[c]=f[MaxPL_IM3[c]]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64
```

does this have to do with variable type, or syntax?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use a numpy float as an index. You need to convert MaxPL_IM3[c] to an integer at this line:

```
IM3_value[c]=f[MaxPL_IM3[c]]
```

Without more details about your PL structure I cannot test conversion methods, but you can try

```
IM3_value[c]=f[int(MaxPL_IM3[c])]
# or
IM3_value[c]=f[MaxPL_IM3[c].astype(numpy.int64)]
```

Comment: I tried this method instead: Hi[c]=np.interp(MaxPL_IM3[c],PL[c],IM3_hi[c])  and it worked